# Simple String comparison is not working

Tags: java, string, linked-list, equals

I need to create a Circular Linked List, with nodes having Rider class objects, with each Rider having a name and a boolean value. Given an text input, the program scans the input and adds riders to a "line"

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{

    Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
    CLLOfRiders line= new CLLOfRiders();
    System.out.print("Welcome to Project 1." +
            "\nWhat is the name of the data file?\n>");
    String input=read.nextLine();
    File f= new File(input);
    Scanner fileread = new Scanner(f).useDelimiter(" - |\n");
    while(fileread.hasNext())
    {
        Rider r=new Rider();
        r.name=fileread.next();
        System.out.println(r.name);
>>>>>       if(fileread.next().equals("Y")) <<<<<   
        r.changePass(true);
        line.addRider(r);
        System.out.println(r.speedPassStatus);
    }
    System.out.println("Finished reading the file.");
    line.showWait();
```

My problem is that the if statement highlighted by the arrows is not running through, so i cannot set Riders booleans to their correct values. By my accounts it seems that this is simple code that should run smoothly? Help please. Sorry for any weird ness this is my first post.

Comment: Do trim() on fileread.next() and see and where are start and end braces for if?

Comment: its just one line if statement

Comment: Ok. Then I would make sure spaces OR case sensitivity OR both not causing the issue.

Comment: i set the delimiter on my scanner to delet all the spaces, so String pass should only be one character long. I tried using equalsIgnoreCase and that didnt do anything either

Comment: Have you tried printing out fileread.next() and see you are really getting "Y"?

Comment: yes i did, it forsure reads the letters as it should be.

Comment: I think you should try printing the values which is being read in if statement and adding the quotes will help to ensure that are there any spaces in the read value

Answer (score 1):

```
...   
r.name=fileread.next();
System.out.println(r.name);
if(fileread.next().equals("Y"))
...
```

you are using `fileread.next()` twice in the loop.

change the second one to

```
if(r.name.equals("Y"))
```

Comment: Sorry for confusion, the 2 reads are different parameters for the Rider class, the name is one part and the second read reads a single character String that i look at to see if the boolean value is true or false. I've tried making a String pass object but it doesnt compare either

Comment: If you print `String s = fileread.next(); System.out.println("'"+s+"'");` what do you get? (notice that I've added single quotes)